# "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Tags: ios, ssl, https, ios10, tls1.2

In iOS 10.2 we are seing this error when we are trying to communicate with several different apis. The wierd thing is that we are only seing this sometimes, in ~ 2 out of 200 requests to the same url. But on the other hand, I can sometimes do 3000 api calls, without seeing the issue.

As far as I've read this is related to ATS. The output also shows us that we are getting an error code that relates to ATS: kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806.

However I do not understand how this can relate to ATS, because of a couple of points:

- The url I am calling is https.
- The server has a valid TLSv1.2 certificate
- I have tried to create an exception, but it doesn't seem to do anything

We've tried to create the exception in different ways, both by allowing arbitary loads, and created the exception for the domain.

Even though it shouldn't be necessary when the server has a valid certificate we have tried to create the exception

This was how we created the exception for the domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>deezer.com</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.2</string>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
          <false/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
```

And this was how we enabled arbitary loads:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

Another wierdness is that we are only seing this in iOS 10 (10.2). When we are testing in iOS 9.3 everything works as expected.

I've made a sample app to reproduce this in.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self Perform];
}

int i = 0;

- (void) Perform
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *sessionWithoutADelegate = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfiguration];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:(@"https://api.deezer.com/chart/0/tracks")];

    [[sessionWithoutADelegate dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error != NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"Got response with error %@.\n", error);
        }

        NSLog(@"%d",i);
        i++;
        if(i <1000)
        {
            [self Perform];
        }


    }] resume];
}
```

Does anybody have an idea for solutions? Thanks

Comment: have you tried removing this key ? <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.2</string>

Comment: Yes I have tried without this, and with TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.0

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue , do you solve it ?

Comment: Yup I did. My issue was because it was set to use the NSUrlSession http client implementation in the project properties. When I set it back to Managed, I solved the issue.